# Не работает wifi модуль после suspend\hibernate

Tags: linux, wifi, драйвер, archlinux

В наличии ноутбук ALienware 13 r2. OS - ArchLinux.

```
➜  ~ uname -a
Linux alienware 4.6.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jul 11 19:12:32 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Wifi карточка.

```
➜  ~ lspci | grep Net 
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
```

Изначально она не заводилась, но эта проблема была решена ещё до меня.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Alienware_13

Wifi работает, но при закрытии\открытии крышки ноута пропадает как устройство.

Более подробные данные о wifi

```
 *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 32
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:03:0f:89
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.6.4-1-ARCH firmware=WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:279 memory:dd200000-dd3fffff
```

Системный лог пока всё работает

```
➜  ~ dmesg| grep wlp
[    5.621623] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   15.325012] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   22.189997] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   24.548511] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   34.757782] wlp3s0: authenticate with 68:a0:f6:36:be:54
[   34.794823] wlp3s0: send auth to 68:a0:f6:36:be:54 (try 1/3)
[   34.796359] wlp3s0: authenticated
[   34.797361] wlp3s0: associate with 68:a0:f6:36:be:54 (try 1/3)
[   34.801220] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 68:a0:f6:36:be:54 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
[   34.804622] wlp3s0: associated
[   34.804648] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready

➜  ~ ifconfig | grep wlp
wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
```

Открыл\закрыл крышку ноута

```
➜  ~ ifconfig | grep wlp    
➜  ~ dmesg| grep wlp        
[    5.621623] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   15.325012] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   22.189997] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   24.548511] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   34.757782] wlp3s0: authenticate with 68:a0:f6:36:be:54
[   34.794823] wlp3s0: send auth to 68:a0:f6:36:be:54 (try 1/3)
[   34.796359] wlp3s0: authenticated
[   34.797361] wlp3s0: associate with 68:a0:f6:36:be:54 (try 1/3)
[   34.801220] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 68:a0:f6:36:be:54 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
[   34.804622] wlp3s0: associated
[   34.804648] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[ 2815.523222] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 68:a0:f6:36:be:54 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

Попытка выгрузить\загрузить драйвер ничего не даёт

```
➜  ~ sudo rmmod ath10k_pci
➜  ~ sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
➜  ~ dmesg| tail            
[ 2816.896879] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1282..], y [1160..]
[ 2817.043835] usb 1-7: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 2817.370704] [drm] RC6 on
[ 2818.247277] PM: resume of devices complete after 2249.224 msecs
[ 2818.247389] usb 1-8:1.0: rebind failed: -517
[ 2818.247392] usb 1-8:1.1: rebind failed: -517
[ 2818.247707] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[ 2818.247710] Restarting tasks ... done.
[ 2818.277244] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics
[ 2818.277252] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160108/nsarguments-95)
➜  ~ ifconfig | grep wlp
```

Comment: Через pastebin или подбные сервисы расшарьте полный файл dmesg после resume.

Comment: И да, вначале попробуйте обновить ядро, по моему у arch доступно уже v4.7.2.

Comment: Вот dbgmsg  после включения http://pastebin.com/LASykk5c
Вот dbgmsg  после открытия закрытия крышки http://pastebin.com/uWQWmGxD

Comment: uname -a
Linux alienware 4.7.2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Aug 20 23:02:56 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Ядро обновил, результата увы не наблюдается

Comment: `rfkill` помогает, если им перезапустить WiFi? Так же не помешал бы ещё `acpidump` с машинки.  Хотя мне кажется, что всё дело в драйвере, который уходит поспать и не возвращается по каким-то причинам. Можно, если есть желание и время, попробовать linux-next собрать руками и проверить.

Comment: Я бы ещё вот на это внимание обратил `[    4.234446] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[    4.234453] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2`, *firmware-5.bin* заливался https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1520343, https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/8984391/

Comment: rfkill не даёт никаких результатов.
степы из bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/152034‌​3 тоже не помогают. 
вот мой acpidump
http://hastebin.com/omovumunoy.avrasm

Comment: По поводу linux-net. Я могу рискнуть поставить из AUR вот этот пакет
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/linux-next-git/ 
Но, что-то мне подсказывает, что обновления ядра не даст ничего. Похоже дело действительно в драйвере.

Comment: И по поводу ошибки  could not fetch firmware file.
Эта ошибка появляется при загрузке ноута, чем меня вводит в замешательство.
Как у меня работате Wifi  если при загрузке он не может подгрузить дрова? При открытии крышки не происходит даже попыток подгрузить модуль.

Comment: Есть интересная строка лога `[    0.502892] pci 0000:00:1c.7: System wakeup disabled by ACPI` 
Где pci 0000:00:1c.7 - мой wifi. Я обнаружил это делая
`echo 1 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/remove`

Comment: `acpidump` -- это такая утилита, которая архивирует таблички ACPI на запущенной системе. Вот архив нужен (та обычно килобайт 200), тогда прояснится и суть последнего вашего замечания.

Comment: Вот мой acpidump https://yadi.sk/d/6R7aoWa6uj47p

Comment: Ваш WiFi `03:00.0` как говорят все выводы логов. В ACPI про него ничего нет, он работает чисто как устройство PCI без всяких дополнений.

Comment: Нуу, может быть, но команда cho 1 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/remove всё равно убивает wifi.  Есть ещё мысли куда можно копать по этой проблеме?

Comment: В список рассылки написать, где девелоперы тусят (linux-wireless@ ?).